# jQuery Mobile - Adding values to selections and transferring value to button

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm new to asking forums so I apologize for anything unsavvy.
I am attempting to create two elements on my jquery mobile page:

1. a select menu where I can have a name "Bob" and attach a phone number as the value of the "Bob Selection"

(I am fine making a select menu and changing the names, I just am not sure how to add a phone number as the hidden value)

2. After that selection is made I want that phone number 'value' to be pulled and added to a call "action" on a button, where one would press it and be able to call Bob.

   I am also able to make a call button but that is with a pre-determined phone number and would like this universal button to be able to change phone number values depending on the selection on the select menu
   (I eventually want these elements on a separate page, but that's further down the road.)

I've tried researching and coding several different ways but can't figure it out.
Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".select").on("change", function() {
    var $number = $(this).val();
    $("a.link").attr("href", $number);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option value="tel:+10245789">Bob</option>
  <option value="tel:+10365487">Bart</option>
  <option value="tel:+10658795">Boone</option>
</select>

<a class="link" href="tel:+10245789">Call him!</a>
```

Comment: This works great when I run the snippet on here, but for some reason the script isn't running in DreamWeaver when I preview in a browser. Also, do you know how I could make it a button and not a hyperlink? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes, you can use a **button** for this. Use button instant of a **link** and value instant of **href**.